# How can i avoid the pageload after clicking the ok button in alert box?

Tags: javascript

AM using this below simple code,after pressing the ok button it allows the page to load.

```
JavaScript:alert('You dont have Access for ' + this.title)
```

How can i avoid the page load after clicking the ok button in alert box.

Comment: Why would you expect that code to stop the page from loading? It just displays the message, and after the user clicks OK the script continues running.

Comment: to use postback check on page_load ?

Comment: What is the purpose of `Javascript:` at the beginning?

Comment: are you using this alert with in `<form>`?

Comment: Show us more code.. what are you exactly doing can't be guessed by this only.. make a fiddle for get answer

Comment: I don't know which event handler you are using. try this... `alert('You dont have Access for ' + this.title);event.preventDefault();`

Comment: on page load we wrote lot of functionality....if i allow to load all the page load codes executing and it takes time to load...

Comment: have you tried my above commented code? let me know the output...

Comment: yes i tried ..it showing an error like " 'event' is null or not an object"..........

Comment: could you show that html line, where you using it?

Comment: actually we are generating the this javascript code via stored procedure in dtabse..afer tht we are assigning this code to asp element that it...

Comment: if it is possible, come to this chatroom http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42482/web-developers

Comment: please provide asp element code in your question...

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this:

```
<a href='somepage.htm' onclick='return showAlert("Some Book Title");'>Title</a>
<script>
    function showAlert(title){
        alert('You dont have Access to: ' + title);
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Clicking the link will not load the next page.
http://jsfiddle.net/CNxL8/